# How to use Promise.allSettled instead of try/catch to catch errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, error-handling, nestjs

I have a method to create products, and to do that, it makes some requests to external services to check if a given id exists on the database. If any of those ids are not found, it shouldn't create the product, therefore, it should return an array with all ids that were not found.

The way someone told me to do it, is by using try/catch for each call... If the id does exists, the try block should fill a variable with the returned object so I can use it afterwards, otherwise, it will push the error message to an array:

```typescript
async createProduct(): Promise <ProductObject> {
    let errors: string[];
    try {
        const productType = await getProductType();
    } catch (typeErr) {
        errors.push(typeErr);
    }

    try {
        const color = await getColor();
    } catch (coloreErr) {
        errors.push(coloreErr);
    }

    if (errors.length) {
        throw Error(errors)
    }

    // if everything goes well
    return product_object;
}
```

Now, altough it works, it doesn't look so good, so the same person told me to take a look into Promise.allSettled(), which is actually a great idea (to make all calls even if they fail), but I'm not sure how to work with it.

How am I supposed to fill an array with messages in case any of them fails (and for each of them) and how am I supposed to asign them to variables?

Btw, pretty sure it doesn't make a difference, but I'm using NestJS with Typescript.

Comment: You might be looking for `Promise.all` instead of `Promise.allSettled` - it won't wait for all promises to settle but fails as soon as the first error happens.

Comment: How are you actually using `productType` and `color` in your code, and how is `product_object` constructed?

Comment: But I do need all errors to happen since I want to return everything that wasn't correct, like, if the colorId and productType were not found, I want to tell the user about both incorrect ids.